# c++, windows - reset command line parameters after handling them

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, command-line-arguments

I have a Win32 application that has a dialog which does certain things only if the process is a restarted process. An outline is as follows:

```
#define CMDLINE_RESTART_PROCESS "--Restart"

BOOL CheckForProcessRestart()
{
    LPTSTR szCmdLine = ::GetCommandLine()
    return ::StrStr(szCmdLine, CMDLINE_RESTART_PROCESS) != NULL;
}

BOOL CMyDialog::InitInstance()
{
    if(CheckForProcessRestart())
    {
        // Do something (like initialize certain variables, controls, etc)
    }
    // Rest of application
}
```

After I detect that the process is a restarted one and initialize those controls and variables, my dialog will do its thing and close.

This dialog is accessed by a menu in the main window. On click of that menu button, when this dialog pops up, it will again detect that it is a restarted process because `GetCommandLine()` will get the original command-line parameters.

My question is, is there any way I can reset the command-line parameters after I handle them?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, are you using command line arguments to open a dialog box from another assembly? Or are the command line arguments shared between the main window and the dialog? If it's the first, then you don't need to reset your arguments, if it's the second, then you shouldn't use command line arguments. Although I feel I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Antonijn, No no. I have an application that does stuff and then restarts itself. Upon restart, this dialog should do some special stuff. That's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this. Your best bet is to make a copy and always check that copy. That copy you can then modify as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I honestly think there should be a way for the calling process to be able to set/reset its own command-line parameters without cloning itself and exiting.

Comment: I think this behaviour is perfectly reasonable, as the data comes from the outside. You can't go back in time and change the way you were called, so why should the system allow you to act as though you could?

Comment: From that point of view it makes sense. But I was thinking, since each command-line is only relevant to that process and since that process alone knows how to deal with those parameters, it should be able to modify them with some restrictions. Just my humble opinion though.

Comment: Anyway, I did exactly this. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a flag, set it `true` at first restart and then do not check and restart while it's `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd rather not use extra variables. I was just wondering if there's a way to actually reset the calling process' command-line parameters.